# Intercept EF update command with insert command

Tags: entity-framework

I need something like "*ModificationRestrictedInterceptor*", which will replace my update row command with creating a copy of this row and in particular column new row should store old row's *ID*. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IDbCommandInterceptor`. Checkout Entity Framework [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) or [this simple tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx) on using command interception.

For your purpose, you should implement `IDbCommandInterceptor.NonQueryExecuting` where you can modify command text before it is executed (via interception context).